# Derivation of stress-energy tensor in curved space-time

Tags: general-relativity

I've a problem about calculating the components of the stress-energy tensor in general relativity. I've learned that if we have an action of the form :
$$
S=\int (R+\mathcal L_{m})\sqrt{-g}d^4x
$$

then we can find the S-E tensor by varying the matter term with respect to either $g_{\mu \nu}$ or $g^{\mu \nu}$ . In fact if we variate with respect to $g^{\mu \nu}$ then we can write it as :
$$
T_{\mu \nu} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta \mathcal L_{m}\sqrt{-g}}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}
$$
Here maybe I neglected some minus signs which aren't important for my question.
And also by variation with respect to $g_{\mu \nu}$ we get :
$$
T^{\mu \nu} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta \mathcal L_{m}\sqrt{-g}}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}}
$$

And now my question : Can we prove that the (co/contra)variant S-E tensor which we defined above are related to each other by a usual rising indices method ? , ie :
$$
T_{\mu \nu}=g_{\mu \alpha}g_{\nu \beta}T^{\alpha \beta}
$$

For an arbitrary Lagrangian density , which may be a functional of the metric or it's derivatives ?

Comment: It would be easier if you expanded the equation and sum the indices from there.

Comment: (Actually the minus *is* important because it is there for one and not for the other!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can but we must use the fact that
$$\delta g^{\mu\mu} = -g^{\mu\alpha} g^{\nu\beta} \delta g_{\alpha\beta}$$
$$\delta g_{\mu\mu} = -g_{\mu\alpha} g_{\nu\beta} \delta g^{\alpha\beta}$$
Then by using chain rule
\begin{eqnarray}
T_{\mu\nu} &=& - \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}} \frac{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}\;,\\
  &=& - \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}} \times \bigg( -g_{\alpha \mu} g_{\beta \nu} \frac{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}    \bigg)\;,\\
  &=&g_{\mu\alpha} g_{\nu\beta} \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}\;,\\
&=:& g_{\mu\alpha} g_{\nu\beta} T^{\alpha \beta}\;,
\end{eqnarray}
where we have defined
$$T^{\alpha \beta} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g_{\alpha\beta}}$$